# anythingslider 1 slide but stuck on the cloned slide

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

am using anythingslider.ja which is great to use, but iv just noticed an issue with it.

The slides are dynamic so on some of my pages there might just be the one slide no for some reason when its only 1 slide it generates start and end cloned `<li>` slide and it stays on the cloned first slide which is very strangly is rendering `<a hre...` as `<span herf...`  !!!

but the middle slide which isnt the clone is all rendered correctly !

so does any one know how to start it using clones if only 1 or make it active on the 2nd `<li>` which is not a clone ?????

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the [latest version of AnythingSlider](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider).

In the newest version, if you don't want any cloned slides, you can set the `infiniteSlides` option to `false`